# json to new listbox item in windows store app C#

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-8, listbox

I have an app for windows 8 that needs to take a Json string and deseriaizes it into DATACONTRACTS and it will display the information I wish in a Listbox that will have a max height and will scroll if greater than the max height.

The problem that im having it not so much as not being able to do it but rather not knowing how to do it.

So far I can deserialize the Json and I can specify where I want each item to go into the UI but what im trying to do is basically a for each item in the array I want it to make a new Stackpanel formatted with Textblocks that will have the information from the Json. I don't know how to this unfortunately and I don't really know what im searching for to get tutorials on how to do it

This is the code I have that takes the items from the json with a helper class and puts them in the Text of the TextBlocks.

```
var _FilterSaleList = new FilterSalesList();
var _Sales = await _FilterSaleList.FindSalesbyFilters();
string _SaleName = _Sales.sales[0].name.ToString();
string _SaleDescription = _Sales.sales[0].description.ToString();
string _SaleName1 = _Sales.sales[1].name.ToString();
string _SaleDescription1 = _Sales.sales[1].description.ToString();
int _TotalResults = _Sales.sales.Length;
SaleTitle.Text = _SaleName;
SaleDescription.Text = _SaleDescription;
SaleTitle1.Text = _SaleName1;
SaleDescription1.Text = _SaleDescription1;
```

This is the XAML code for the Listbox with 2 Stack panels already in it.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="SaleTitle" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="SaleDescription" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                        
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="SaleTitle1" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="SaleDescription1" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Below is an image of how I would like it to look.
even though everything works this way like I said I would like it so that each item from the json will make a new stackpanel and display the information as in the image. I don't know what its called when this is done so even a simple hint as to where to look would be great!

http://puu.sh/2biMZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML there is a very nice feature called Binding, which allows you to simply bind an object or a list of objects to visual element. This way, you don't have to "build" the graphical user interface manually in C# code.

This is a very large topic, so you should probably have a look at what is MVVM, it will help you leverage the power of Binding : http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Both-Windows-8-and-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start/Building-Apps-for-Both-Windows-8-and-Windows-Phone-8-03-Model-View-ViewModel

But for now, what you could is :

1/ Define your ListBox as following, with a DataTemplate for the ItemTemplate property :

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SalesListbox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <TextBlock x:Name="SaleTitle" Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="SaleDescription" Text="{Binding description}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The DataTemplate will tell how each item of the list should be rendered. You should also notice how we used Binding for the Text properties in each textblock. It's bound to `name` and `description` which are the name of the properties in your model.

And then you can populate your ListBox with your data :

```
var filterSaleList = new FilterSalesList();
var salesByFilters = await filterSaleList.FindSalesbyFilters();
SalesListbox.ItemsSource = salesByFilters.sales;
```

Comment: I thought it would have to do with Binding just wasn't to sure how to go about doing it. I was looking at the MVVM and just couldn't grasp it but ill be checking out your link and perfect this binding art :)